# Server uses Cors but UI still gets allow-origin error

Tags: asp.net-core, cors

Hello i am trying to issue a `http` `get` request to a `.NET Core Console App` from my `Angular 2` frontend and i get the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:9300/api/getusers' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

For me it is curious since i have enabled `CORS` on the server side as you can see below in the `Startup` class.

**Startup**

```
public class Startup {

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
            services.AddOptions();
            services.AddMvc();
        }
        public IConfiguration Configuration;
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {
            Console.WriteLine("request delievered");
            Debug.WriteLine("Entered Server !");
            app.UseMvc();
            app.UseCors(x => { x.AllowAnyHeader(); x.AllowAnyOrigin();x.AllowAnyMethod(); });
        }
    }
```

I make the request from the `UI` like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService{

    private static baseUrl:string="http://127.0.0.1:9300/api";

    constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
    }

    getClientsAsync():Promise<User[]>{
      let route=UserService.baseUrl+"/getusers";
      var data=(this.http.get(route)  //should i have some headers here?
      .map(resp=>resp)
      .catch(err=>
          Observable.throwError(err)

        ) as Observable<User[]>).toPromise<User[]>();

      return data;
    }
}
```

**P.S** I have tried with `Postman` and the request works ,however here in the `angular 2` i have not included any `headers` for my `http.get` method.Could this be the problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put `UseCors` before `UseMvc`.

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {
        Console.WriteLine("request delievered");
        Debug.WriteLine("Entered Server !");
        app.UseCors(x => { x.AllowAnyHeader(); x.AllowAnyOrigin();x.AllowAnyMethod(); });
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

This is because UseCors adds a middleware (as does UseMvc), and middleware are executed in order from top to bottom. So the request never gets to the CORS middleware.